# IDN-aware Windows command line WHOIS utility

Tags: windows, command-line, domain-name, international, whois

I use Mark Russinovich's excellent [`whois.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897435.aspx) to perform WHOIS queries from the command prompt in Microsoft Windows. This works very well, but it does not handle IDNs. For instance, if I try to check my domain `ändlöslängtan.se`, I try `whois ändlöslängtan.se` which gives no match. If I manually transform `ändlöslängtan.se` to `xn--ndlslngtan-p5af5u.se` (e.g. using Google Chrome's address bar and the clipboard), it works. It would be much more convenient, however, if the CLI utility could do this transformation automatically.

**Question:** Is there a lightweight Windows CLI utility, similar to Mark Russinovich's `whois.exe`, that automatically transforms IDNs?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the "transformation" (to `xn--ndlslngtan-p5af5u.se`) you did is? I don't understand enough about internationalization to know off the top of my head.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan: I don't know the details, but the thing is that an internationalised domain name (like `ändlöslängtan.se`) automatically is transformed by the browser (or other software) to an ASCII-only version, which is the 'actual' domain name (but which is normally not shown to the user). Have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux [whois](https://github.com/rfc1036/whois) client by Marco D'Itri  does supports IDNs, so I came up with a Windows porting. For example, your query shows up as in the following:

```
>whois ändlöslängtan.se
# Copyright (c) 1997- .SE (The Internet Infrastructure Foundation).
# All rights reserved.

[cut]

# The data is in the UTF-8 character set and the result is
# printed with eight bits.

state:            active
domain:           xn--ndlslngtan-p5af5u.se (A☼ndlA¶slA☼ngtan.se)
holder:           andrea4342-00001
admin-c:          -
tech-c:           -
billing-c:        -
created:          2011-02-20
modified:         2014-02-10
expires:          2015-02-20
transferred:      2014-02-10
nserver:          ns2.loopia.se
nserver:          ns1.loopia.se
dnssec:           unsigned delegation
status:           ok
registrar:        Loopia AB
```

@sahmeepee method was correct albeit indirect, but you would need to install IDN+ICONV libraries. In my porting I preferred to statically link them, in order to obtain a standalone executable.

You can find the first release along with the source code in my [github](https://github.com/mfornasa/whois/releases/tag/v5.1.1_win32_alpha2) page.

Comment: Good. I prepared a [new version](https://github.com/mfornasa/whois/releases/tag/v5.1.1_win32_alpha2) which correctly supports non-ASCII characters in the server response (as in the "domain:" line above).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find exactly what you wanted, but the gnu libidn package has a program called "idn" which has an "-a" option providing the conversion you are after. It wasn't that easy to find binaries for Windows, but I came across this link to binaries for a slightly older version:

http://josefsson.org/gnutls4win/libidn-1.19.zip

You should be able to use idn -a and pipe the output into your whois command to achieve the result you were looking for. To make it more convenient, you could make a batch file which takes your domain name as a parameter so you don't have to type both commands every time.

Comment: I haven't yet understood how to use this utility. It returns something that looks right, but isn't (`xn--dllgtan-9ebd278h.se`). It also complains: `libidn: warning: libiconv not installed, cannot convert data to UTF-8`. The new version (1.28) also fails, but in a somewhat different fashion (`idn: could not convert from ASCII to UTF-8`, no output at all, `libiconv` present).